# Podspec dependency specific swift version

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Is it possible to specify different Swift version for pod dependency (in podspec file)? I've updated my pod to Swift 4.2 but one of the dependencies is still on Swift 4.0. When I run `pod lib lint` it would try compile everything using Swift 4.2 but of course would fail because the dependency code is not 4.2 compliant.

Comment: any fixes for that?

Comment: I haven't found a way at that time :(

Comment: seems like dependency's podspec
should have s.swift_version = '4.2' or needed version. so you need to contact and pr to dependency pod to have this.